# setState function not working on child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-tsx

I have the following code in my React component:

```
class TheComponent extends Component{

    constructor(props) {

        super(props);

        this.state = {
            a: '',
            b: ''
        };
    }

    output = (data) => {

        this.setState({
            a: data.a,
            b: data.b
        });
    }

    render(){
        return(<ChildrenComponent outputValues={this.output.bind(this)}/>);
    }
}
```

When I call the `output` method from the same component, it works perfectly well, and the state is changed successfully. But when I call it from my `ChildrenComponent` it doesn't work, and the state never changes.

So I've added the following code to the `output` function in order to find out what's going on: `console.log(this.setState)`. And the result is that the "setState" function **is there**.

So, if the function `setState` is properly bound to `output`, why it doesn't work? And why it **does** works only when output is called from the current component?`

Comment: You don't need to bind like that if you're using an arrow function.

Comment: I am actually not able to repro this behavior, passing to my child component works fine: https://repl.it/repls/TealLivelyScale

Comment: yes @y2bd, this is very strange. It should work, but not sure what's happening.

Comment: You're right @Colin, but even when I remove the binding, it doesn't work either

Comment: @Captain can you post your full code please?

Comment: The full code has more than 100 lines of code :[ it's too big

Comment: @Captain what makes you think it's not working? I don't see you using your state anywhere in your code, which makes me think we need to see MORE of your code to help you.

Comment: I assume `render() = > {` is a typo when you typed out the example code? This should be `render = () => {`

Comment: @larz, there I edited the code and added the state details.

Comment: Sorry @EvilGeniusJamie, I misstyped it. Now I fixed it in the code example. I don't understand why setState is not working

Comment: @Captain seeing how you set the initial state in the constructor isn't...constructive ;) . WHAT makes you think that when you call `output` the state isn't being updated?  You aren't using `this.state.a` in your `render` method, so I have trouble helping you trouble shoot.  Maybe add a `console.log(this.state.a)` inside your `render` method and see if that displays what you expect on the re-render? Maybe `console.log(data)` and make sure there is a` data.a` in there inside your `output` method.  We are only seeing half the code.

Comment: @larz, yes, but I have made the console.log, and also I have the react extension for chrome, and checked the state with both of them, and it doesn't change. I'm fixing this using Redux, but I will keep this question open in case somebody else has the same issue, and can find the answer here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code looks pretty good to me. I think you're just getting a bit confused with what `setState` does. `setState` is a built in React function and running `console.log(this.setState)` will therefore always log a function, specifically that function.

I'm not sure how you are calling your prop in the child component, but the example below allows the child component to set the parents state to the `data` object above the `render` functions `return` as well as logging the parent state to the console.

```
class TheComponent extends Component{
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            a: '',
            b: ''
        };
     }

     setValues = (data) => {
        this.setState({
            a: data.a,
            b: data.b
        });
      }

     outputValues = () => {
         console.log(this.state);
     }

      render(){
        return (
            <ChildrenComponent set={this.setValues} output={this.outputValues}/>
            <p>{this.state.a}</p>
        );
      }
    }
```

```
class ChildrenComponent extends Component{
      render() {
        const data = { a: 'foo', b: 'bar' };
        return (
            <button onClick={() => this.props.set(data)}>change parent state</button>
            <button onClick={this.props.outputValues}>console.log parent state</button>
        );
      }
    }
```